# Игнорирование методов в функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

После рефакторинга моими чудесными руками, программа начал вести себя не корректно. К примеру:

```
def clickAndTime(x, y, t1 = 0, t2 = 0):
    time.sleep(t1)
    pg.click(x, y)
    time.sleep(t2)
    print('Был сделан клик. Но на самом деле клик был проигнорирован без ошибок...')
    print('Принт кстати вывелся')
```

Функцию сократил для наглядности. Эта функция вызывается через функцию->функцию->функцию->функцию там еще чето проверяется, чето крутится, вертится. В общем мой код стал гораздо читабельнее, с ним приятно работать, но он не работает ))) Че у нас внутри? main.py и 5 модулей к нему. В каждом модуле импортятся всё теже модули и всё написано без применения ооп - обычные функции. Еще стоит добавить что функция постоянно используется в приложении и она работает, но именно через большую цепочку событий она игнорирует. Также функция в этой  цепочки иногда срабатывает.

Comment: Можно подробнее про "не работает"? Вы проверяли, заходит ли программа в эту функцию? Использовали отладчик, чтобы посмотреть, не обходит ли программа эту функцию из-за непрохождения какой-нибудь проверки уровнем выше? В данный момент ошибок в Вашем коде я не вижу, а потому советую выложить его весь, чтобы участники сообщества могли найти проблему.

Comment: @V-Mor принт выводится всегда, значит заходит в функцию, поэтому смысл выкладывать 6 функций которые приходят к этой и она отрабатывает, но часто игнорирует клик.

Comment: Тогда ещё раз попрошу поподробнее про "не работает". По какому критерию Вы определили, что не работает? Как оно должно работать и как работает сейчас?

Comment: @V-Mor pg.click это pyautogui. То есть должен сработать клик в определенную точку. Но сам клик часто(через раз) игнорируется, но функция отрабатывает, так как принт выводится. Если эту функцию я вызываю отдельно, даже через длинную цепочку. Она отработает корректно. Возможно дело в том что основная функция в бесконечном цикле, и оно пока добирается до нужного места асинхронно выполняет всё остальное, но этого тоже не может быть, так как там тоже стоит принт и я бы это заметил.

Comment: Вот обычные функции, а не классы - это путь к тому, что рано или поздно у вас совпадут какие-то названия функций или переменных. Лучше всё же делать классы, хотя бы внутри класса всё может называться без боязни пересечься с другой сущностью.

Comment: А нет ли у вас теперь таких функций, куда вы передаёте список, словарь или ещё что-то mutable в виде default аргумента и меняете это внутри функции? А то может из-за этого приколы. Других вариантов не приходит в голову.

Comment: @CrazyElf Нет, такого нет. С дебагера на брекпойнте всё работает. Исходя из этого я решил попробовать поставить слип, но проблема не решилась.

Comment: @Incover Ну тогда вариант, что вы какие-то переменные путаете, например, используете какие-то глобальные переменные, а при этом перезаписываете их внутри функции локальными с таким же именем. Впрочем, что-то такое я уже выше писал.